# How to measure total memory usage of all processes of a user in Python

Tags: python, memory, metrics

I like to use these commands to see my memory usage on my servers:

```
ps -u $USERNAME -o pid,rss,command | awk '{print $0}{sum+=$2} END {print "Total", sum}'
```

What would be the best way to collect that total sum in a Python script? I had a look as psutil but that module only collects global memory information and there is no way to filter it down by user.

Comment: Do you care about platform dependence at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty simple using [`psutil`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/). You can just iterate over all processes, select the ones that are owned by you and sum the memory returned by [`memory_info()`](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.memory_info).

```
import psutil
import getpass

user = getpass.getuser()

total = sum(p.memory_info()[0] for p in psutil.process_iter()
                               if p.username() == user)

print('Total memory usage in bytes: ', total)
```

Comment: Many thanks! This pushed me into the right direction. Using a list comprehension like that will not work because for some processes  `memory_info()` will throw an `AccessDenied` error, so I just wrote a normal loop and put a try-catch block in there.